# ember dynamically add content

Tags: ember.js

My ember route is like this:

```
App.AdminRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
       return this.store.find('user', {validated_timestamp: 'null'});

    }
});
```

which return list of users like this:

```
User #1
User #2
User #3
User #4
```

I want to see user details when I click any of the user. Right now it display like this:

```
User #1
User #2
User #3
User #4
user_id: 1
email: test@gmail.com
first_name: test
last_name: dummy
```

But I want to under clicked user; like this:

```
User #1
 user_id: 1
 email: test@gmail.com
 first_name: test
 last_name: dummy
User #2
User #3
User #4
```

How do I do it in ember.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember components are a great way to achieve your desired functionality. Enjoy this [working example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/febukoguruje/1/edit)

Here's how all this works. Your new index route:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each user in model}}
      {{user-details user=user selectedUser=controller.selectedUser action='changeSelected'}}
    {{/each}}
 </ul>

</script>
```

Users are now displayed using the `user-details` component:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/user-details">
  <p class="pointer" {{action 'clickedUser'}}>{{user.id}}</p>
  <ul {{bind-attr class=hideDetails:hidden}}>
    <li>{{user.detail}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

And the logic:

```
App.UserDetailsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  hideDetails: function(){
    if(this.get('selectedUser') !== this.get('user')){
       return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }.property('selectedUser'),
  actions: {
    clickedUser: function(){
      this.sendAction('action', this.get('user'));
    }
  }
});
```

This component is passed in three properties. The user object, an action string (corresponds to the name off the action on the controller, and the selectedUser object, which we define on the controller. When the user's name is clicked, it fires of the action called 'clickedUser' on the component. This action sends the action 'action' which is a property passed into the component. This property corresponds to the name of an action on the controller, and passes it one parameter: the user object that was just clicked:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedUser: null,
    actions: {
      changeSelected: function(user){
        this.set('selectedUser', user);
      }
    }
});
```

Now this changeSelected sets the `selectedUser` to the user that was just clicked. Every single one of our components has a computed property that observes the controller's `selectedUser` property:

```
hideDetails: function(){
    if(this.get('selectedUser') !== this.get('user')){
       return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
}.property('selectedUser')
```

So changing the `selectedUser` on the controller will make each component reevaluate this property. If the `selectedUser` is not the user that the component displays, hideDetails returns true. Notice in the component that I bound the attribute `<ul {{bind-attr class=hideDetails:hidden}}>` to the list of details. The colon means that if hideDetails evaluates to true, set the css class `hidden` to the `ul`. the css is:

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

So every single detail list is hidden except for the one that is the last selected user. Let me know if you have any questions!